# Will a BlocListener react to changes in a Bloc's variables before a new state is emitted?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a quiz game that is managed by a bloc. When the user clicks an answer button, the bloc processes the submission, provides immediate UI feedback via a private variable called _quizgameStateTracker (to let the user know if correct/incorrect), then waits 3 seconds before emitting a new state with a new question index to update the UI with a new question.  The feature works correctly for the first 2 of 3 questions, but when the 3rd question is answered, the 3 second delay happens prior to the UI updated instead of immediately. When I place breaks in the code, it looks like the code executes identically for all three questions, but only the final question experiences the 3 second delay between click and UI update.
So my question is: Does the UI require a new state to be emitted from the bloc or does the BlocListener have access to the private variable _quizgameStateTracker and can react to changes in it?

Here's the Bloc

```
class GameplayBloc extends Bloc<GameplayEvent, GameplayState> {
  List _quizgameStateTracker = [];
  Quizplaymodel _quizPlayDoc;
  int _tourStopIndex;
  Tour _tour;
  int _numQuizQuestions;
  List _quizQuestionArray;
  List _quizResultsArray = [];

  GameplayBloc() : super(GameplayInitial()) {
    on<InitializeGame>(_initializeGame);
    on<SubmitAnswer>(_processAnswer);
  }

  _initializeGame(event, emit) {
    ...// not relevant for question
  }

  _processAnswer(event, emit) async {
    event.controller.stop(canceled: true); 

        // Variables
        final quizObject = _quizQuestionArray[event.questionIndex];
        final answersArray = quizObject.answers;
        final numAnswers = answersArray.length;
        final correctAnswerObject =
            quizObject.answers.firstWhere((answer) => answer.isCorrect == true);
        final answerSelected = quizObject.answers[event.indexSelected];
    
        // Determine index of correct answer by converting the answersArray into a map whose keys are the array's indices and whose value is the isCorrect property - then returning the key(array index) whose isCorrect value is true
        var arrayIndex = 0;
        final mapFromAnswersArray = {
          for (var item in quizObject.answers) arrayIndex++: item.isCorrect
        };
        final correctAnswerIndex = mapFromAnswersArray.keys
            .firstWhere((k) => mapFromAnswersArray[k] == true, orElse: () => null);
    
        // Update the _quizgameStateTracker's stateOfAnswerButtons
        var updatedStateOfAnswerButtons =
            _quizgameStateTracker[event.questionIndex]['stateOfAnswerButtons'];
        for (int i = 0; i < numAnswers; i++) {
          if (i == event.indexSelected) {
            if (answerSelected.isCorrect) {
              updatedStateOfAnswerButtons[i] = StringConstant.answeredCorrect;
            } else {
              updatedStateOfAnswerButtons[i] = StringConstant.selectedIncorrect;
            }
          } else {
            if (i == correctAnswerIndex) {
              updatedStateOfAnswerButtons[i] = StringConstant.correct;
            } else {
              updatedStateOfAnswerButtons[i] = StringConstant.notSelected;
            }
          }
        }
        _quizgameStateTracker[event.questionIndex]['stateOfAnswerButtons'] =
            updatedStateOfAnswerButtons;
    
        // Update other variables of _quizgameStateTracker
        _quizgameStateTracker[event.questionIndex]['hasAnswered'] = true;
        _quizgameStateTracker[event.questionIndex]['answeredCorrectly'] =
            answerSelected.isCorrect;
        if (answerSelected.isCorrect) {
          _quizgameStateTracker[event.questionIndex]['pointsEarned'] =
              _quizgameStateTracker[event.questionIndex]['pointsRemaining'];
        } else {
          _quizgameStateTracker[event.questionIndex]['pointsEarned'] = 0;
        }
        _quizgameStateTracker[event.questionIndex]['indexOfAnswerSelected'] =
            event.indexSelected;
    
    
        // Pause 3 seconds to allow user to see results of selection
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {});
    
        // Determine if last question
        int lastQuestionIndex =
            event.tour.tourStops[event.tourStopIndex].quizQuestions.length - 1;
        if (event.questionIndex == lastQuestionIndex) {
          event.controller.reset();
          emit(TapState(false));
          return emit(QuizEndState(_quizgameStateTracker));
        } else {
          // continue to next quiz question
    
          event.controller.reset();
          // event.controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
          // event.controller.animateTo(0, duration: Duration(seconds: 20));
          // emit(TapState(false));
    
          int nextQuestionIndex = event.questionIndex + 1;
    
          return emit(IntialState(
              quizgameStateTracker: _quizgameStateTracker,
              tour: _tour,
              quizPlayDoc: _quizPlayDoc,
              tourStopIndex: _tourStopIndex,
              questionIndex: nextQuestionIndex));
        }
      }
    
    }
```

Here's the code for the answer buttons:

```
  final Color color;
  final String questionType;
  final Tour tour;
  final int tourStopIndex;
  final int questionIndex;
  final quizgameStateTracker;
  final AnimationController controller;

  const AnswerButtonsBuilder(
      {Key key,
      this.color,
      this.questionType,
      this.tour,
      this.tourStopIndex,
      this.questionIndex,
      this.quizgameStateTracker,
      this.controller})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnswerButtonsBuilder> createState() => _AnswerButtonsBuilderState();
}

class _AnswerButtonsBuilderState extends State<AnswerButtonsBuilder> {
  bool showSubText = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int numAnswerChoices = widget.tour.tourStops[widget.tourStopIndex]
        .quizQuestions[widget.questionIndex].answers.length;
    List answersArray = widget.tour.tourStops[widget.tourStopIndex]
        .quizQuestions[widget.questionIndex].answers;

    return BlocListener<GameplayBloc, GameplayState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is TapState) {
          showSubText = state.isTapped; 
        }
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: numAnswerChoices,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    if (widget.quizgameStateTracker[widget.questionIndex]
                            ['hasAnswered'] !=
                        true) {
                      context.read<GameplayBloc>().add(TapEvent(showSubText));
                      context.read<GameplayBloc>().add(SubmitAnswer(
                          tour: widget.tour,
                          tourStopIndex: widget.tourStopIndex,
                          questionIndex: widget.questionIndex,
                          indexSelected: index,
                          controller: widget.controller));
                    }
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: widget.quizgameStateTracker[
                                  widget.questionIndex]['hasAnswered']
                              ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)
                              : Colors
                                  .transparent, 
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: ColorSwitch.type(
                                  widget.quizgameStateTracker[
                                          widget.questionIndex]
                                      ['stateOfAnswerButtons'][index]),
                              width: 2)),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        widget
                            .tour
                            .tourStops[widget.tourStopIndex]
                            .quizQuestions[widget.questionIndex]
                            .answers[index]
                            .answerText,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: ColorSwitch.type(widget.quizgameStateTracker[
                                        widget.questionIndex]
                                    ['stateOfAnswerButtons'][
                                index])), 
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ))),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                showSubText
                    ? (widget
                            .tour
                            .tourStops[widget.tourStopIndex]
                            .quizQuestions[widget.questionIndex]
                            .answers[index]
                            .isCorrect
                        ? Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, bottom: 16),
                                  child: Text(
                                      widget
                                          .tour
                                          .tourStops[widget.tourStopIndex]
                                          .quizQuestions[widget.questionIndex]
                                          .answers[index]
                                          .subText,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          color: Colors.white)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        : SizedBox(height: 0))
                    : Container(),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding `emit(QuizResult(quizgameStateTracker: _quizgameStateTracker));` prior to the 3 second delay, the issue was resolved. I am assuming that the UI requires a new state to be emitted in order to update properly. If anyone can add additional detail regarding the lifecycle of Bloc and how it accesses Bloc variables, I would appreciate any details. Thanks.